# Ember build in production environment is not loading addon's css file

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an addon that I built myself which contains a single css file (`addon/styles/<addon-name>.css`).

When I use this addon on my Ember project and I do a build in development mode on that project everything works fine but when I do a production build the css file is not loaded.

Why is this happening? How can I use the css in my main app?

Comment: Are you properly `app.import`ing it? Can you share some code?

Comment: I'm not using `app.import`, should I use it on my app? Shouldn't it load the css like it loads the templates and components?

Comment: I think your css file should be named as `app.css`, not `<addon-name>.css`. And then it shouldn't be needed to `app.import`ing this.